# Beyond basic CRUD, how can users update or delete many records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, bulkupdate

I have a very typical Rails app with strong use of CRUD.. but as we know, they always relate directly to a single record in the model.

#### Update Many: i.e. "Mark Selected as Archived"

On my `controller#index` view, I want to be able to allow users to bulk delete or bulk update records in a particular way.

This is similar to Gmail where you can select multiple emails in the list, and choose `change label` or `move` from the *toolbar menu*.

Is there a pattern to achieve that in Rails?

[image]

I know I can delete whatever I want using SQL or ActiveRecord queries. I'm more concerned about what the controller and routes should look like, and if there's a pattern for that already.

Answer (score 4):

You can add new routes for handling actions on multiple records (say, posts) in single request:

Do changes as below:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
  collection do
    put :bulk_update
    delete :bulk_destroy
  end
end
```

It will add these new routes in addition to regular CRUD routes:

```
bulk_update_posts     PUT       /posts/bulk_update(.:format)       posts#bulk_update
bulk_destroy_posts    DELETE    /posts/bulk_destroy(.:format)      posts#bulk_destroy
```

Now, add corresponding controller actions for the same:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
before_action :fetch_posts, only: [:bulk_update, :bulk_destroy]

def bulk_update
  @posts.update_all(permitted_params)
  redirect_to posts_path
end

def bulk_destroy
  @posts.destroy_all
  redirect_to posts_path
end

private

def fetch_posts
  @posts = Post.where(id: params[:post_ids])
end

def permitted_params
  # Decide for yourself
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform various CRUD operation on multiple records also where you pass ids of selected record in where condition which will return collection of ActiveRecord objects and on that collection you can perform update multiple, delete multiple.

```
User.where(:id =>[23,45,68,123]).update_all(:is_active => true)
User.where(:id =>[23,45,68,123]).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the list of `ids` to the backend and then do `User.where(id: [1,2,3]).destroy_all`

Comment: I'm more concerned about what the controller and routes should look like, and if there's a pattern for that already. I know I can delete what ever I want using SQL or ActiveRecord queries. I'll make this clearer in my question.